# .NET MySQL Connector Stored Procedure Parameters Order

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-connector

I'm iterating through a Dictionary(Of String, String) to pass parameters to a MySqlCommand, key being the name of the variable IN in the stored procedure and value being the value I'd like to use in the stored procedure.

It seems that the stored procedure parameters supplied are order dependent in that if they're not supplied in the order that the IN arguments are listed in the stored procedure it won't execute and give errors.

This is counterintuitive since I provide the exact name of the argument as the parameter key and if one parameter is out of order then the whole stored procedure is rendered useless.

Is there any way to pass parameters order independent?

Comment: I'm assuming this is from a .Net language?

Comment: Yes, using the mysql .Net connector.

Comment: I'm having this problem only since installing mysql.data 8.0.11. Did you resolve this at all?

Comment: This is 6 years old. I ended up going with something other than a Dictionary, that was ordered. @ssed